# XCode c++ file reference

Tags: c++, xcode, ifstream

I'm trying to write a few algorithm programs practising for Google Code Jam but I can't get XCode to read from an input file (easily).

I have added the file to the project and it appears in the left hand file navigation bar.  But I can't reference it relatively.  In Code::Blocks I just input from "FileName.txt" and it works but with XCode it just can't find it.

If I put the full file path (i.e. /Users/myname/Documents/Google Code Jam/ProjectName/ProjectName/FileName.txt) then it works but that just seems ridiculous.

Is there anything I can do to get XCode to work?  When I added the file I ticked the copy file into project directory and also the add to target executable.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Set the working directory for the debugging session to the folder where you have your txt file. Are you using Xcode 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this and the comments by Julio Gorgé is just what I needed. The default working directory when running in debug mode is some esoteric folder (as you can see in iOS if you include `system("pwd");` at the beginning of your main().

It's in the "Options" tab of the *Edit Scheme...* menu that you can tick "Use custom working directory" and find the test file you put in in the *Arguments* tab.